# VC++2008 Debugger doesn't find library sources

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, debugging

An exception got thrown from a lib I use in my project. As I looked at the callstack, I clicked at the lib function that threw the exception. An "Open File" dialog popped up, prompting me to tell it **where the lib source is located**. Now clearly something is wrong. This should happen automatically somehow. How do I tell VS where to look for *all* files from that lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer: you just need to use the dialog that pops up. Do tell it where to find **this particular file** and henceforth it will always look there for **any** file belonging to that lib. Nice.